# Passive "to be brought" in Korean

Tags: verb

If the verb "bring" is 가져오다 or 가져가다, what will be the passive of it? Because it seems there is no passive form for 오다 or 가다.

Comment: If you *really* want to make a passive voice with 가져오다/가져가다, you can say 가져와졌다/가져가졌다, but I think in all practical cases it would be better to find another verb or sentence structure, as @jick says in their answer.

Comment: Edit to the comment above: I should've said 가져와지다/가져가지다. -졌다 is past tense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think 가져오다/가져가다 has a passive form.  Instead you will use active form or different verbs depending on context - note that in Korean one can easily "emphasize the object" by changing word order or using topic marker -은/는.

So, for example:

> The box was brought here by me. -> 그 상자는 내가 가져왔다.  (Active form, but "the box" is the topic.)
>
> The box was brought here on a cart. -> 그 상자는 카트에 **실려왔다**.  (Alternative passive verb.)
>
> The new insect species was then brought to America. -> 이 새로운 종의 곤충은 이후 아메리카로 **전파되었다**.